# FATAL Exception Main android(acessing webservice via kSoap)

Tags: android, exception, ksoap

i am new to android development, i am trying to access my web service locally hosted via UltiDiv  ,when i runn the app it gives me Fetal Exception, i have added INTERNET and NETWORK_STATE permission in android manifest  but its still the same. web service name is connecto and method name is DbRead and takes a string phone

```
    // here is the code 
    package finalProject.test.webService;
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
    import android.app.*;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    public class FinalWebServiceDemoActivity extends Activity {
    // some parameters regarding your web-service to be invoked
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/connecto";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "DbRead";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.8:8080/connecto.asmx";

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    call();
    }

    public void call()
    {
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("phone","1234");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new                             SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        String strRes = result.toString();

        tv.setText(strRes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText("Exception...");
        Log.i("exception", e.toString());
        StackTraceElement elements[] = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {      
            Log.i("File", elements[i].getFileName());
            Log.i("Line", String.valueOf(elements[i].getLineNumber()));
            Log.i("Method", elements[i].getMethodName());
        }
        }
        }
         }
```

Comment: and what says logcat?

Comment: 03-18 01:37:42.329: E/dalvikvm(30558): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.fyp.connecto_messenger.MainActivity.call

Comment: i have included the external jar file of kSoap. i dnt know then why this error. .

Comment: try to clean your project.

Comment: Done . . ! .still same  . .

Comment: you don't have external jar file in buildpath. Right click on project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Add external JARs.

Comment: Ksoap jar is already included there with Android 4.0.3 and Android dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by replacing Ksoap 2.6.0 with 2.4  :-)